# woocommerce gallery showing only 1st image on product page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gallery

I have the following website: [link](http://dev2.pixlgraphx.com/corvettes2/) and its single product page that shows the product info and shows the product images on the gallery.

**Problem:** As you can see on the following screenshot it only shows the 1st image but if i click on any the thumbnails the image is not displayed at all.

[image]

Here more details of what happens when click on the thumbnails:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgZfj.jpg

Inspecting the site i found that the images are there but In some i need to use margin-left: 9000px and top: -300px in order to be displayed correctly. But i can do this customization because some products have several images and they're not same width and height.

**Question:** Why are they not displayed? Is there a way to show all pictures correctly when I click on any of the thumbnails?

Comment: Can you share  the like of the site/projec?

Comment: ugh i forgot to include it on the details but here it is: http://dev2.pixlgraphx.com/corvettes2/

Comment: http://dev2.pixlgraphx.com/corvettes2/product/2005-2013-corvette-c6-z06-widebody-conversion-kit-aftermarket-custom-painted/

Answer (score -1):

I checked the code. This might be because of the plugin/theme conflict.
Do check the Woocommerce -> System Status and look for errors.

Try switching the theme and see if the issue is solved and if the problem is still there then try disabling plugins one by one and see if the issue persists.